# Bluish hue on the edge of the photo

Tags: exposure, shutter-speed, iso, panasonic-lumix

I really do not know what and how this happened to my Panasonic Lumix FZ40 after using it for about 4 years (still not intelligible enough on using it), and I do not know the right term for it to be found on Google or to even ask this question.

The bluish hue with ripples on the edge found above appears when the ISO is set to 1600 and disappears when the shutter speed is below 20.

Photo above has shutter speed of 20 and ISO of 1600. Photo below has shutter speed of 60 and same ISO as the photo above.

**TL;DR - There is bluish hue on the edge of the photo, how, what and why did this happen?**

[image: This photo has shutter speed of 20 and ISO of 1600.]
[image: This photo has shutter speed of 60 and same ISO as the photo above.]

Comment: The first image doesn't really tell us anything. The artifact could be there as well, but the image is so dark the darker part in the artifact is just darker than already dark. If most of the sky is already at the black point, then anything darker (e.g. a lower signal on the raw data from the sensor) will only be as dark as the black point as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the artifact, the sky is a mundane blue overlain with concentric circles. I don’t think this is a camera problem specifically. However, keep in mind that I have been wrong more than 1000 times this month. I think the problem is due to the fact that the camera saves the data as a JPEG file. This is a scheme developed by the Joint Photo Experts Group. The JPEG method compresses the file data to save storage space. The file is then reinstated when called up for viewing, editing, or printing. The scheme is somewhat like how you might condense a book by casting out all the “and”, “is”, “a”, “the” etc . to save space on a hard drive. When viewed, the software attempts to restore, but this is never seamless. Same for a digital picture file; the sky is mundane blue, the software cast out pixels for storage. If the file is viewed and saved, some additional pixels are cast out. In other words, the rebuilding process is flawed. I suggest you look at your image-editing software, try different software. Also, I think this camera can save in “raw”. Try that approach. Also look at the camera’s menu; have you selected the largest file size? If not, the situation is exacerbated.

Comment: Your answer seems to make the most sense.
The artifact also appears on Photoshop. This camera can only shoot in JPEG, sadly. About that "largest file size"? I'll give it a try.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The bluish hue with ripples on the edge found above appears when the ISO is set to 1600 **and disappears when the shutter speed is below 20**.

This does suggest it's a mechanical issue with the shutter.  I'd suggest reporting this to Panasonic and see if they can offer an opinion.  It could be a design "feature" (i.e. working withing design specs even if it's not perfect) or it could be a fault.